# How Java paints JComponents?

Tags: aspectj, instrumentation

I would like to know how does Java paint JComponents on the screen?

I am usign AspectJ to instrument all calls to Graphics2D methods. For example, whenever there is a call to Graphics2d.Draw(Shape) from the application I am able to capture that call.

Does Java use the Graphics class to also paint JComponents, lets say JButtons? For example, there is a JButton on my application and I want to capture the methods to graphics class for painting that JButton on the screen? I don't know how to do this.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I tried to override the JButton class and the PaintComponent method. If I do this than I can capture the calls to Graphics methods used to draw that JButton.

How can I capture those calls without overriding the specific JComponent class?

Comment: You are using call() or execution() join points to capture these calls? Please, submit your AspectJ code.

Comment: I guess that AspectJ weaver is failing to access the graphics 2D external library (because it is a external library), so the weaving isn't performed. When you override the method on your code, AspectJ can access the code and perform the weaving. Probably the library of graphics 2D are not on your -inpath of ajc compiler.

Answer (score 1):

yourJButton.repaint(); causes swing to invoke the paint() method. You should not invoke paint directly, but should instead use the repaint method to schedule the component for drawing. This method actually delegates the work of painting to three protected methods: paintComponent, paintBorder, and paintChildren.

Comment: Thank you Travis.I understand you.Each JButton class has a paintComponent method.In order to paint the button,this method calls some methods from Graphics class such as drawLine setColor etc.I want to capture these calls to Graphics methods.I have created a new button JButton myBtn = new JButton();I attach this to a panel,and when this is painted on the screen I want to capture the calls to Graphics class methods.If I extend the class of JButton and override the paintComponent method,then I can capture calls to Graphics class methods,eventhoug I dont call the paintComponent myself.